# Chrome App offline installer for ICT4D

Tags: google-chrome, offline, google-chrome-app

I'm interested in using Chrome (Packaged) Apps for [ICT4D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_and_communication_technologies_for_development) applications.

Is it possible to distribute Chrome Apps without being online / using the Chrome Web Store at all?

The big goal would be to distribute packaged apps using only USB flash drives / pendrives.

I would like to use Chrome Apps for their ability to target all desktop (& laptop) OSs. (Even fairly old ones. I might have to also distribute Chrome with the app.) Using web technologies (and laptops / computers) makes sense for the content-creation part of the app (and to reuse code), I think. The data could be distributed *with* the app in one neat offline bundle.

I will target mobile OSs with a simpler content-consumption app, but will probably try to reuse a lot of the code. In Android at least the app might be able to simply keep an `.apk` copy of itself to distribute to others offline.

Comment: What type of devices would you want to distribute on? For ChromeOS you may be able to set up several Chromebooks as "enterprise enrolled" and pre-install some apps. Not sure of the details on how that works.

Comment: @MatrixFrog I've expanded my use case slightly, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put an platform specific Autoruns on the USB stick that run chrome with the --load-and-launch-app

**Windows**

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --load-and-launch-app=.

C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --load-and-launch-app=.

**Mac**

/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --load-and-launch-app=.

**Linux**

/opt/google/chrome/chrome --load-and-launch-app=.